# How to change the amount of time a tooltip is displayed for in a UWP app?

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

In my app, I've created an Ellipse and defined the ToolTipService for it.  The tooltip is displaying fine, except that I'd like it to show for a longer period of time (looks like it currently defaults to disappearing after 5 seconds).  There doesn't seem to be any properties on the ToolTipService such as ShowDuration (eg. in Silverlight XAML there is ToolTipService.ShowDuration Attached Property).

How can I change the duration of the tooltip display? (Below is code snippet)

```
<Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource MainToolTipTemplate}" Background="Black" Opacity="50" ></ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: As far as I know, we may not be able to change the show duration of the tooltip display in UWP. So how about using a [Flyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx) to show the tip in your scenario?

Comment: I ended up going with a ContentDialog for now, however, the Flyout also seems like a possibility.